# How to access the Devise Omniauth omniauth fb appid?

Tags: devise, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my devise.rb file in the initializers folder i've set:

config.omniauth :facebook, 'APPID', 'APPSECRET',

how do I access these values in my controller?  I need to write the appId out for something else but can't seem to figure out to get at these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it weird that you'd want to do that since you want to keep your id and secret safe...

But one way, is creating a new file, let's call it constants.rb and put in your initializers folder. Like this:

```
APPID = "string"
APPSECRET = "string"
```

And then you can use those strings in your devise file like this:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, APPID, APPSECRET
```

You can use these constants in the same way in your controllers. Also, don't forget to restart your app.